# SpagoBI charts: X axis values overlap when lot of values

Tags: spagobi

I'm using SpagoBI to draw charts from values stored in a Database.

If there are a few values, chart is showing properly, but if I have a lot of values the X axis legend overlaps.

**Example**:

**Few values**

[image: Image with a few values]

**Lot of values**
[image: Image with a lot of values]

**I want to know if is possible to define the number of values shown at the X axis keeping all the data in the chart.**

For example: If I have 10 hours just show 0:00 1:00 2:00 .... 10:00 instead of all data in the X axis, keeping all the points in the chart.

Thanks